# Advice on Ninject Implementation

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject

I'm developing my first project using Ninject (an MVC web application) and have a question regarding the correct/best use on Ninject.

I have set up a NinjectModule that binds an interface to a concrete class, but now I want to create instances of the interface object within my code.  To achieve this I have written the following method:

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory {

  private class MyServices : NinjectModule {
     ...
  }

   public static IMyRepository GetMyRepository()
   {
      IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyServices());
      return kernel.Get<IMyRepository>();
   } 
}
```

and this seems to work fine...

```
IMyRepository tempDB = ControllerFactory.GetRoomarRepository();
```

My question is, this the right/best way to achieve the result I'm looking for?  I'm guess I'm concerned about the overhead of creating the Kernel instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the documentation: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3 and look at the sample project.

Comment: Thank you Remo.  Apologies in advance, but I think I might be about to try your patience...  Let's say I have an Interface and I have two classes that implement that Interface.  In my code, a simple console application (for example) I want to create, an instance of that Interface. Do you/can you/should you literally define a class based on NinjectModule and then create a Ninject StandardKernel object on-the-fly and use that to Get() the concrete instance?

Comment: No normally you have one kernel that is configured in the bootstrapper of the application. It is used as little as possible. Many application have just one call to get that create all necessary services. In case of MVC3 you don't need any call to get at all.